# VueJS: Binding a variable with 3 potential values?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-component

I'm working on a base `<CardButton>` component and have 3 variable card sizes related to whether there is an `<img>` or not. If the `imgPosition` variable is on the left, the box looks like this:

[image]

If it's on top then it should look like this:

[image]

And if there is no image, the text should just be centered like so:

[image]

Both 'left' and 'top' work fine, but how can I implement a 3rd condition of 'none'? Right now it keeps the styling and alignment of the other two and I don't want that.

I have the `imgPosition` prop that has a default of left, but even when I make it `type: String` and have the default, I get stuck at how to implement it in the template. The ternary is in place of a `v-if`, but I can't use 3 conditions there correct?

```html
<div imgPosition === 'left' ? 'img-left' : 'img-top' : 'img-none'>
```

Doesnt work (or make sense for that matter.) How can I implement these 3 conditions?

If you need any more information please let me know! Cheers!  I've posted the simplified version of my component below sans any other borders, stylings etc.

CardButton.vue

```
<template>
  <div
    :class="[
      imgPosition === 'left' ? 'img-left' : 'img-top',
      'card-button-wrapper',
    ]"
  >
    <img :src="imgURL"/>
    <div class="labels">
      <div>{{ label }}</div>
      <div>{{ subLabel }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
.card-button-wrapper
  display: flex
  position: relative
  border-radius: 10px
  width: max-content
  max-width: 630px
  max-height: 340px
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)

.img-left
  width: 100%
  height: 160px
  img
    margin: 24px 40px

.img-top
  flex-direction: column
  align-items: center
  text-align: center
  .labels
    margin-bottom: 50px
  img
    width: 138px
    height: 138px
    margin: 50px 75px
    margin-right: 72px
    margin-bottom: 50px

.labels
  flex: 1
  display: flex
  justify-content: center
  flex-direction: column
  white-space: pre-line

</style>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CardButton',
  props: {
    imgURL: {
      type: String,
    },
    imgPosition: {
      type: String,
      default: 'left',
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
    },
    subLabel: {
      type: String,
    },

  },
}
</script>
```

Example.vue

```
   <CardButton
      imgURL="/woman-panel-station.svg"
      imgPosition="left"
      label="Top Text"
      subLabel="Bottom Text That is longer"
    />
    <br />
    <CardButton imgURL="/woman.svg" imgPosition="top" :label="`Top Text\nBottom Text" />
    <br />
    <CardButton label="Some Random Text" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `imgPosition` variable as part of the class name.  For example, with a template literal:

```html
`img-${imgPosition}`
```

This will result in a class named "img-left", "img-top", or "img-none".

```html
<div :class="[`img-${imgPosition}`, 'card-button-wrapper']">
```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      imgPosition: '',
      positions: ['top', 'left', 'none']
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.img-top {
  background: yellow;
}
.img-left {
  background: limegreen;
}
.img-none {
  background: #358293;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div :class="[`img-${imgPosition}`, 'card-button-wrapper']">
   I'm a <code>&lt;div&gt;</code>!
  </div>
  <button v-for="pos in positions" @click="imgPosition = pos">{{ pos }}</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```